# Can you send different view models to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, view, viewmodel

Say I am implementing a view for Food. (ASP.NET MVC2)

Then depending on the type (say fruit or vegetable for example) I will change the view.

Can I do this without creating a seperate view for fruit and vegetable?

I.e. Say we have url structure like http://localhost:xxxx/Food/{foodID}

and don't want

http://localhost:xxxx/Veg/{foodID}

http://localhost:xxxx/Fruit/{foodID}

So I want to be able to change the view depending on the type. I'm using a tabstrip control from telerik, to give you an idea of the difference in the views - it'd just be say - not displaying one particular tab for Veg, and displaying it if fruit, for example.

Can a view accept two different view models ? so when we hit http://localhost:xxxx/Food/{foodID} the code determines what type the object is (Fruit or Vegetable) then sends either FruitViewModel or VegetableViewModel ? If I just send one viewmodel how can I control the logic to display or not display certain things in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define `FoodViewModel` as a base class and have `FruitViewModel` and `VegetableViewModel` extend it, you could have `ViewPage<FoodViewModel>` and pass in either. Then, your view can check for which specific subclass it got and render the appropriate output.

Alternatively, if the only difference between `FruitViewModel` and `VegetableViewModel` is that one is Fruit and one is Vegetable (but all other properties are shared, i.e., `Name, Calories, Color, Cost`), have a `FoodType` property on the shared `FoodViewModel` and use it to conditionally render the appropriate output.

Comment: "Then, your view can check for which specific subclass it got and render the appropriate output." - how do you do this in the view ??

Comment: <% if (Model is FruitViewModel) %> etc.

Comment: The way I read the question, the only difference between the two views is going to be something like tabStrip.Tab[i].Visible = isFruit; This is why I didn't think it would be wise to duplicate the other n lines of View code. If your view will have more substantial differences based on the type of food, definitely have different Views.

Answer (score 1):

What alternative is the best depends on how much the Fruit and Veg Views differ:

### Alternative 1:

You can create two different Views (you can pass the view name to the View method):

```
public ViewResult Food(int id)
{
    var food = ...
    if (/* determine if food is Veg or Fruit */)
        return View("Fruit", new FruitViewModel { ... });
    else
        return View("Veg", new VegViewModel { ... });
}
```

By returning a different View the url doesn't change (as it does when using `return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", ...)` which implies a HTTP redirect.

### Alternative 2:

You can have a common `FoodViewModel` extended by both the `FruitViewModel` and the `VegViewModel`. Then your FoodView can be of type `FoodViewModel` and decide what to show in your View code.

Comment: I thought he wanted to use the same View for both, but just set an enabled or visible property on a single tab with the rest of the view being equal in either case.

Comment: well initially I did but the real goal is just to keep the url structure together not splitting it between fruit and veg

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you need to change is the tabstrip setting. You can provide a property called "ShowTabItem" on your ViewModel, then bind that property to your TabStripItem in your view.

```
public class FoodViewModel
{
    Food _food;

    public FoodViewModel(Food food)
    {

    }

    public bool ShowTabItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _food.Type == FoodType.Vegetable;
        }
    }
}
```

Bind your ShowTabItem property to the Visibility or Enabled property of the tabstrip item. (whatever fits)

then your controller will simply be

```
public ActionResult Food(int id)    
{
    Food food = getFood(id);
    return View(new FoodViewModel(food));
}
```

Let your ViewModel decide what needs to be displayed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 this is the best solution, except I would put the logic for this in the controller and just make the ShowTabItem a simple property.  This means you can change the logic for defining if the tab should be show in the controller, and not in your view model, which should just be a dumb holder for the data the view needs